# Some introductory reverse engineering help on finding a string

Tags: penetration-test, reverse-engineering, software, ctf, assembly

I understand the crackme I am researching is from 2007, however this was the point in my life when I initially became interested in reverse engineering and wish to complete it for nostalgia sake. Following on from this question, I intend to pursue these challenges through more modern avenues that are more beginner friendly.

**Link to the tutorial:** [crackme1 por nitr0k1ller](https://foro.elhacker.net/ingenieria_inversa/tutorialcrackme1_por_nitr0k1ller-t337915.0.html).

**Link to the crackme binary:** [download](https://mega.nz/#!HtBiAbqa!eReYrnW3UhG9J2MXtsREEu_wRwjYGdsV7qy7wwCpbJc)

**Password:** elhacker.net

I have opened this in **x32dbg**, pressed run twice (because the first click shows ntdll.dll as the crackme is a 32bit executable) and discovered the crackme's entry point. However, from here on I am a little stuck, despite trying random options such as `search for > all modules > string references and doing an ASCII string search`.

- How can I search for "&Check"
- How can I patch the file to change 0 to 1, activating the crackme's button

Whilst this question might seem specific to the crackme above, I am asking a general question on how to search for strings using x32dbg in such a way that I can confirm I have understood any responses to my question properly.

It is a bit frustrating, as I have enough knowledge to have finished this without asking for help, I just got stuck on string searching.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Dump" section at the bottom of x64dbg / x32dbg, you can right click and select "Find Pattern". In there you can search for ASCII, Unicode (UTF-16), or UTF-8 encoded strings in memory.

Cheat Engine is another very useful tool for memory scanning, and may be more appropriate if you're trying to find a specific bit of memory with contents that change periodically.

If the executable is simply checking that the string you entered matches a hard-coded one, you don't need to do anything - just enter that text and you win.

If the executable is doing a more complex check you might want to just patch it to always pass regardless of whether the correct key is entered. This is usually done by finding the conditional jump that checks whether the key was valid (e.g. `jz`, `jnz`, `jbe`, etc.) and patching it to an unconditional jump (`jmp`) or removing the jump entirely (replace it with `nop`).

For example, this code checks whether `rax` is zero, and if so it jumps to a failure case:

```
48 85 C0    test rax, rax
75 1F       jnz fail
```

Since you *never* want it to fail, you'd replace the `jnz fail` with a pair of `nop` instructions:

```
48 85 C0    test rax, rax
90          nop
90          nop
```

Sometimes you'll run into the opposite case. This code tests if `rax` is equal to 4, and jumps to a success case if it is:

```
48 83 F8 04     cmp rax, 4
74 2A           jz success
```

Since you always want it to succeed, you can swap the `jz` out for a `jmp`:

```
48 83 F8 04     cmp rax, 4
eb 10           jmp success
```

What the exact instructions are doing, which conditional jump you want to patch, and which type of patch you want to do is down to the specific situation. That's the challenge. You'll have to figure that part out on your own :)

Press spacebar while highlighting an instruction in x32dbg or x64dbg to edit that instruction. You can then type in a replacement instruction. If you tick the "Keep Size" option, it will prevent you from accidentally overwriting the next instruction by entering a replacement instruction that is too large. If you check the "Fill With NOPs" box, it will pad the leftover space with bytes if you enter an instruction that encodes to something smaller than the instruction you're overwriting.

Once you've made your changes you can save the patched copy of the file. Go to File -> Patch File (Ctrl+P) to see a list of the changes you've made. If you don't want to include certain changes, you can untick them.

[image: Screenshot of patches dialog]

When you've picked which changes you want to apply, click Patch File in the bottom right to patch the file on disk.

Comment: The executable has a disabled button, so before I can even search for a serial key I need to enable it by finding "&Check" and flipping a bit to enable the button.

Comment: Another question, what if I wanted an instruction that was bigger than the available space?

Comment: If you need an instruction that's larger, you generally need to use a code cave or similar technique.

Comment: I know this is a big ask, but could you please upload a video with how to do this using x32dbg? I searched for string using the dump part at the bottom and found nothing. It is clearly a very small confusion somewhere.